# Can I use state in components while using Redux or Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Is it OK to Using a component state for just to handling form data, while the main data and other stuff of the application will be stored in the Redux store?

I don't want to use redux-form instead manually dispatch it to the reducers**

Answer (score 1):

`Redux` comes into the picture when we want to manage the state across different component. It provides a centralize store where state of all the components are managed.

When talking about forms, in most cases form data is only limited to the component is which is being used. So, in that type of scenario there is no need to link them to centralized store using `redux`. A simple way is to store them in the component state and get it processed. Afterwards, you can store the output of that in `redux` store according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

It is okay to do that. You can keep a local state in the component. `state = {}` in class components, `const [localState, setLocalState] = useState()` for functional components.

Or you can use custom hooks for handling your local state needs. Check out `useInput` or `useForm` custom hooks that are developed by the community.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course. Some things go best in component state, some go best in a parent component, some go in Context, and some go in Redux. There is little use in putting everything in Redux, it just causes a lot of boilerplate and every component tries to update when the store changes.

You put things in Redux when different components that are at different places in the HTML tree use the same data, and it changes during the app's lifetime (things like the user's language don't change often and go in Context). You use it when you want to store your app's state to restore it later (which exact menus are currently open or closed is usually not that important) and when you want to keep track of state changing using the Redux dev tools.